# Concerning the sequence $ \sum_{p \le n , p} \big\lfloor\frac{\log n}{\log p}\bigr\rfloor/n$ where p is prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence

The sequence $\Bigg( \dfrac{\sum_{p \le n , p \underbrace {is prime}} \Big\lfloor\dfrac{\log n}{\log p}  \Big\rfloor}{n} \Bigg)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded , my question is what is the lim sup of this

sequence ? Is the sequence convergent ? If it does , what is the limit ?

Answer (score 5):

We have$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\leq n}\left\lfloor \frac{\log\left(n\right)}{\log\left(p\right)}\right\rfloor =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\leq n}\left|\left\{ m\in\mathbb{N^+}:\, p^{m}\leq n\right\} \right|=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p^{m}\leq n}1=\frac{\pi\left(n\right)}{n}+O\left(\frac{\log\left(n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}+\frac{\log\left(n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=O\left(\frac{\log\left(n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
 where $\pi\left(n\right)=\sum_{p\leq n}1$.

Expanding a little bit, note that $$1)\left|\left\{ m\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:\, p^{m}\leq x\right\} \right|=\left|\left\{ m\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:\, m\log\left(p\right)\leq\log\left(x\right)\right\} \right|=\left\lfloor \frac{\log\left(x\right)}{\log\left(p\right)}\right\rfloor $$ $$2)\,\textrm{We have the bound }\left|\left\{ p:\, p^{m}\leq x,\, m\neq1\right\} \right|=O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right)$$ $$3)\,\textrm{By Prime Number Theorem }\pi\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right).$$